I am encountering an issue with receiving a null value for the Postman bearer token in a Laravel middleware
I am currently experiencing an issue with my Laravel API on a cPanel-hosted environment. When making API requests from Postman with a Bearer token in the Authorization header, the token is not being received by the application. This setup works as expected on my local environment, where the Bearer token is successfully passed and retrieved by the application. However, in the cPanel environment, the Authorization header appears to be missing or stripped out.
I have already tried the following troubleshooting steps:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With"
</IfModule>

I am getting a null value when trying to retrieve the Bearer token using $request->bearerToken() in middleware.
I am using cPanel for my hosting environment.
EDIT:
getallheaders() results are
[
    "company-code" => "SCH20241",
    "User-Agent" => "PostmanRuntime/7.37.3",
    "Accept" => "/",
    "Cache-Control" => "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token" => "c8f2eecf-9553-4004-b3e1-428161324ed7",
    "Host" => "uat-myedulight.in",
    "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection" => "keep-alive",
    "X-Https" => "1",
]


what is the results in getallheaders() ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php You can throw it in the public/index.php file to debug before even laravel get instantiated. This will tell you if the issue is in laravel or before it (cpanel/nginx or apache)

getallheaders() => I'm getting this result  
[
"company-code" => "SCH20241"
"User-Agent" => "PostmanRuntime/7.37.3"
"Accept" => "/"
"Cache-Control" => "no-cache"
"Postman-Token" => "c8f2eecf-9553-4004-b3e1-428161324ed7"
"Host" => "uat-myedulight.in"
"Accept-Encoding" => "gzip, deflate, br"
"Connection" => "keep-alive"
"X-Https" => "1"
]
Using apache.

edit your question and post the result there. As you can see therer is no authorization header

In my Laravel middleware, I'm encountering a null value when trying to retrieve a token using this code: $token = $request->bearerToken();

of course you get null, there is no authorization header in your request. Doesnt matter if laravel allow it or not if it doesnt exist in the first place. add the Authorization header in your postman request.

I have already passed the token in the API. This is the header response I'm receiving from Postman "https://prnt.sc/DhaDuZanixc7". "https://prnt.sc/wA3uSNLIv6V4"

can you show the "headers" tab of postman too ?

https://prnt.sc/cICsSJJyJ2ZU

check with your sys admin or provider why the headers dissapear before reaching the server
